# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError after upgrading Jetpack Compose to 1.0.0‑beta07

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting the following error running `observeAsState` on a LiveData object after I upgraded Jetpack Compose to 1.0.0‑beta07.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method startReplaceableGroup(ILjava/lang/String;)V in class Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer; or its super classes
```

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#1.0.0-beta07) says that the error is expected upon upgrade and in order to resolve it one must recompile libraries dependent on Compose.

I do not know have to do that. I tried making the project again and also clearing and rebuilding it with no avail.

Here are the dependencies in my project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
    implementation "io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:datetime:0.4.0"
    implementation "io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:datetime:0.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activityVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.30"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-alpha07"
}
```

and these are the versions:

```
ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-beta07'
        activityVersion = '1.1.0'
        appCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
        constraintLayoutVersion = '2.0.2'
        coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
        coroutines = '1.3.9'
        lifecycleVersion = '2.3.1'
        materialVersion = '1.2.1'
        roomVersion = '2.3.0'
    }
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps it's the issue mentioned here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#version_100_2

Comment: @jspcal hi. yeah that is the issue. same note was mentioned in the link I provided, but your link too does not include a hint on how to recompile the said dependencies.

Comment: Could you add your dependencies from `build.gradle`?

Comment: @RyanM I added the dependencies.

Comment: Try to update 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta06' to beta07

Comment: Probably `implementation "io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:datetime:0.4.0"` is outdated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `runtime-livedata` dependency is outdated:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta06'
```

You should update that to use the same version as the rest of your Compose dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
```

Which would be effectively:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta07'
```

Answer (score 27):

Anyone using [Navigation with compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) should also update the navigation library to the latest available version.

In my case, I was using

```
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha10"
```

and had to replace with

```
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha01"
```

Comment: It gave me a hint that it was nav related by pointing to my `rememberNavController()` call. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For me, It was updating  constraint layout compose  version to `1.0.0-alpha07`
`androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:$constraint_layout_version`

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was updating to

```
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha02")
```

and

```
implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:0.10.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Paging compose was required to update from 1.0.0-alpha07 to 1.0.0-alpha11

```
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha11"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by adding this dependency -

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using

```
def compose_version = '1.0.1'
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, sometimes removing and readding the troubled component helps. For me, it was crashing on some optional parameter in a composable. I removed the parameter and readded it, and then it worked...