# Jetpack Compose crash NoSuchMethod in Composer or super class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I just updated Jetpack Compose (as well as `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion`) to `1.0.0-beta07` and immediately started receiving this crash on app start. Downgrading removes the crash.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method startReplaceableGroup(ILjava/lang/String;)V in class Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.runtime.Composer' appears in /data/app/~~VFlRsIkoEwB2qQlR7w1oWw==/*app.name*-itKCOLTh4XCfwxxLqBwHkg==/base.apk)
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67611497/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-after-upgrading-jetpack-compose-to-1-0-0-beta07. The key is to update all libraries that depend on compose. In my case the error was caused by an outdated hilt_compose_navigation version

Comment: Post your dependencies

Comment: Thank you @jns! That was helpful. In my case, it was related to jetpack compose navigation dependency

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by **updating Compose dependencies to *1.0.4***

And also added in build.gradle (Module: app) under dependencies {...}

```
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            // Treat all Kotlin warnings as errors
            // allWarningsAsErrors = true
            freeCompilerArgs += '-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
            // Enable experimental coroutines APIs, including Flow
            freeCompilerArgs += '-Xopt-in=kotlin.Experimental'
            freeCompilerArgs += '-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies'
    
            // Set JVM target to 1.8
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
```