# Android Compose-Navigation 2.4.0-alpha2 crashes with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

After updating the version of the compose navigation dependency, my app crashes directly at launch with the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method drawRect-w2WG-Gw$default(Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope;JJJFLandroidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawStyle;Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/ColorFilter;Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/BlendMode;ILjava/lang/Object;)V in class Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope$DefaultImpls; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope$DefaultImpls' appears in /data/app/~~pBKRwWSGSd6Trycrlz_8bw==/com.example.wunderguard-9YsObT0GJC9oUzrTLizqog==/base.apk)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.Background.drawRect(Background.kt:111)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.Background.draw(Background.kt:103)
...
```

When using an older version I get the Exception described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67611497/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-after-upgrading-jetpack-compose-to-1-0-0-beta07)

Do you have an idea, what might cause this problem?
These are my dependencies (compose_version = '1.0.0-beta07')

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha02"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-beta01"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
```

}

Comment: For sure the problem is in alpha2 :D

Comment: Can you try with beta08?

Comment: After Updating Compose to beta08 and Kotlin to 1.5.10 it works! Thanks for the hint I didn't realise there was a beta08 already :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can try with `1.0.0-beta09` and update Kotlin compiler to `1.5.10`, this configuration

```
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta08"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    

    // Compose
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.0-beta08"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.0.0-beta09"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta09"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0-beta09"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.0.0-beta09"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta09"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta09"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta09"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:compose-theme-adapter:1.0.0-beta09"
}
```

Comment: After Updating Compose to beta08 and Kotlin to 1.5.10 it works! Thanks for the hint I didn't realise there was a beta08 already...

Answer (score 4):

The version `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha02` contains this commit:

[Upgrade to Kotlin 1.5.0, KSP to 1.5.0-1.0.0-alpha09](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/e238bad05f051639c06b8a1df67d1c1eb0fa917b)

- Update your compose dependencies to **`1.0.0-beta08`**
- Update Kotlin compiler to **`1.5.10`**

Answer (score 0):

Do you read your posted link?
[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError after upgrading Jetpack Compose to 1.0.0‑beta07](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67611497/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-after-upgrading-jetpack-compose-to-1-0-0-beta07)?
Obviouse that you have to use the same version for all compose libs.

Comment: androidx.navigation:navigation-compose is not available in beta. Accordig to (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_240_2) it should work with compose beta 07 and above...

Compose Compatibility
androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha01 is only compatible with Compose version 1.0.0-beta07 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Compose to beta08 and Kotlin to 1.5.10 solved the problem for me!