# android studio starting up instant shut down the app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Its the first time that this happens, when I run the app on android studio with kotlin , even with the default app, that android studio creates it gives me this error , the simulator opens the app but insta crash it with the message:
"The app have stopped"

This is the logcat with the error:

```kotlin
2021-06-06 19:22:42.598 7817-7817/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7817
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method drawRect-w2WG-Gw$default(Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope;JJJFLandroidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawStyle;Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/ColorFilter;Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/BlendMode;ILjava/lang/Object;)V in class Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope$DefaultImpls; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope$DefaultImpls' appears in /data/app/~~1FERHlT2eRJdt1EprXEfMQ==/com.example.myapplication-m2_HPlQabeWTbDjc_hkOyA==/base.apk)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.Background.drawRect(Background.kt:111)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.Background.draw(Background.kt:103)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedDrawNode.performDraw(ModifiedDrawNode.kt:102)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:260)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:259)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:121)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:259)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:53)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeApi29.record(RenderNodeApi29.android.kt:156)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.updateDisplayList(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:229)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:210)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:82)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:260)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:259)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1788)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:259)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:53)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeApi29.record(RenderNodeApi29.android.kt:156)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.updateDisplayList(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:229)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:210)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:800)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:249)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performDraw(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:67)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:249)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performDraw(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:67)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:249)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performDraw(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:67)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:249)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performDraw(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:67)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:249)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:800)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:656)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
2021-06-06 19:22:42.599 7817-7817/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:806)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:565)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Any ideia of how to solve it?

Comment: maybe this post can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836958/android-compose-navigation-2-4-0-alpha2-crashes-with-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: @Dievskiy thanks for the suggestion , I tried that but didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same error as yours by updating compose version to 1.0.0-beta08 and update kotlinCompilerVersion to 1.5.0 in app gradle file and (classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10") in project gradle file and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

when your view not get or problem in your view, the android app gives a *FATAL EXCEPTION* error
Please check your view or view with any casting.